# How can I create a dynamic list based navigation?

Tags: 2007, navigation

I have a question regarding sharepoint 2007 custom top navigation.

How can I create this kind of navigation? (dropdown with customizable `<li>` content.) I know that sharepoint uses table for this :)

check out some samples here :

- http://www.healthychildren.org/
- http://www.conservation.org/Pages/default.aspx
- http://my.clevelandclinic.org/default.aspx ( this is cool )

I'm not talking about static navigation. There's no problem if we use static navigation.

UPDATE ----------------------------------- :
Okay guys! you all are awesome. Thanks for the answers ( new answers are welcome ).
It turns out to two temporary conclusion.

For those who wants to give a different look and usability enhancement, your could try [this](http://tothepoint.inproc.com/creating-mega-drop-down-navigation-in-sharepoint-2007-with-jquery/)
, but if you want something more sophisticated ( using dynamic images, etc ). im still thinking the list is better option. or maybe you have a better thought?  share with us!!

Will update this regularly ;) Cheers.
Nick

Comment: Need your advice guys. Regarding the best practice. where do we put this customized menu ? master page or as a webpart ? i heard we cant put anything "custom code" on the master page?? ( mind my question, im a web designer im not too technical on sp :) )

Thanks. Gday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the series of blog posts starting here [Creating Mega Drop Down Navigation in SharePoint with jQuery – Part 1](http://tothepoint.inproc.com/creating-mega-drop-down-navigation-in-sharepoint-2007-with-jquery/)  What you are looking for is usually called a "mega menu".

**Update due to broken link:**

This is available in WebArchive here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160308164315/http://tothepoint.inproc.com/creating-mega-drop-down-navigation-in-sharepoint-2007-with-jquery/

That is why we should not have link-only answers!

Comment: Interesting Marc!! Will take a look. really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that you will find that for those sites listed that they have either implemented their own custom navigation control that emits rendered HTML or that they have used the ootb navigation control and added a whole bunch of CSS customisations in order to get the appearance desired.

Take a look at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/modonovan/archive/2008/05/30/custom-navigation-in-sharepoint-the-full-monty.aspx) which has a pretty good overview of the topic.

Comment: Hi Michal,

Yes, i've done this also. 
im thinkin of something more "automatic" so when they create a subsite or whatever. it will automatically shown. or i may say modifying sp default menu ( some says its from .dll ) really appreciate this :).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Templates-based menu control for SharePoint](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/templates-based-menu-control-sharepoint/) by Waldek Mastykarz

Comment: Inetersting Jaap. indeed will take a look on it! ;) THanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also try building your own SiteMapProviders.

Comment: Hmm.. have you done it before John ? i will browse this sitemapproviders.. Thank you :)

Comment: I've built them before.  It's pretty straighforward except you have to worry about concurrency.  You also have to remember that the sitemapprovider is stored in the application cache, so the same object is being loaded for all sitemap requests.

Answer (score 0):

I've done work in the past where I created a custom navigation provider and used SharePoint lists to maintain the configuration.

Comment: Mike, where do you put it? masterpage or as a web part? do you have any reference for this ? :) Thank you so much.

Comment: In my case it was a "custom navigation provider" baked into the MasterPage.  If you do a search on the net you can find a few examples like this one:  http://faraz-khan.blogspot.com/2008/11/writing-custom-navigation-provider-for.html  In my case I used both the default menu provider for localized nav for the site collection and then the custom provider for global navigation across applications and site collections.

Comment: You mentioned wanting it to be automatically populated.  This could potentially be done with an event receiver to log new sites to the list, but they would likely need to be organized given the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is set up a "task" list type, then you add hyperlinks fields (you can attach several) to the new list. 
Then you populate the list with the users and the hyperlinks you want them to be exposed to. 
Then create a view with the hyperlinks and the filter set to [Me] and your done!